# Problems in Partial Derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm trying to compute the Partial Derivatives for the equation:

$$k(a, b) = a^2 \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2b^2} (x-y)^2\right)$$ w.r.t. $b$

$x$ and $y$ are known; both $a$ and $b$ are hyper-parameters.

I'm a little confused on this problem...

Comment: Your question implies that $k$ is a function of variables $x$ and $y$, and that you need to find $k'(x,y)dx$ and $k'(x,y)dy$. This doesn't really work-out that well with "$x$ and $y$ are known".

Comment: Hi~ I have modified my question....x and y are just training data.

Comment: Sounds like all you need to do is to find the derivative of $k(a,b)$ by $a$ (regarding $b$ as a constant) and then by $b$ (regarding $a$ as a constant). So where exactly is the problem with that?

Comment: So I guess you are trying to perform a minimisation problem? So do you require finding $\partial_a k$ and $\partial_b k$?

Comment: Thank you @Chinny. Indeed, I'm trying to perform a minimisation problem for a regression model. But I'm not familiar with Partial Derivatives for composite functions T.T

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Barak. I am not familiar with Partial Derivatives on composite functions...

Comment: You're welcome. Please see answer below, if it doesn't help then I'll remove it.

Comment: Thank you @'barak'. Your answer is quite helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is just to compute the partial derivative w.r.t to b then do as follows

$$k(a, b) = a^2 \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2b^2} (x-y)^2\right) = a^2\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2b^2}f(x,y)\right)$$

since the only place where $b$ occurs is in the exponent we can take the derivative as
$$
\frac{\partial k}{\partial b} = a^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial b}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2b^2}f(x,y)\right)
$$
to take the derivtive of the exponent we proceed as
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2b^2}f(x,y)\right) = \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2b^2}f(x,y)\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\left(-\frac{1}{2b^2}f(x,y)\right)\\
=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2b^2}f(x,y)\right) f(x,y)\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\left(-\frac{1}{2b^2}\right)\\
=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2b^2}f(x,y)\right) f(x,y)\left(-\frac{-2}{2b^3}\right)
$$
which leads to 
$$
\frac{\partial k}{\partial b} = \frac{a^2}{b^3}(x-y)^2\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2b^2}(x-y)^2\right) 
$$

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you Chinny...thanks a lot for this detailed answer. It really helps a lot!!! Thank you!

Comment: No probs. hope you solve your problem :).